# Create dynamic table with the dynamic column in php and mysql

Tags: php

First I would like to congratulate the site, I already learned a lot from him. already tried in Brazil forum found nothing. I am in need and creates a dynamic table with dynamic column. following example!

```
  Local           01/12/2014 |02/12/2014 |03/12/2014
  Esteira         12.00   |  12.00    |  12.00
  Mesa            10.00   |   6.00    |   6.50
  Balança         13.50   |   8.00    |    9.50
  ponteira        10.00   |   9.00    |   23.00
  import          13.50   |   10.00   |   46.00
```

the code that use for table dinamic

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Produção</th>
                              <th>GREC</th>
                              <th>Realizado</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <?php do { ?>
                            <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $row_datatable['DataProd']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row_datatable['GREC']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row_datatable['Realizado']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } while ($row_datatable = mysql_fetch_assoc($datatable)); ?>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: could you please edit the question to include your problem statement? what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: and why facebook tag?

Comment: what I need is to generate a dynamic table in php where the columns are dynamic. The columns are the rows of the database table in the sample are dates. Not to use  case if,  because they are dynamic.

Comment: not facebook , was wrong.